# WebClient encoding queryParams spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I have trouble with WebClient encoding query parameters when the value of one parameter is decoded JSON value to String.

One of queryParams value is :

```
[ { "var": "report_days", "op": "=", "val": "7" } ]
```

it is decoded from HTTP method : ?`filter=%5B%7B%22var%22%3A%22report_days%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22%3D%22%2C%22val%22%3A%227%22%7D%5D`.
So decoding to `MultiMap<String, String>` is executed correctly, but in `uriBuilder` the exception is thrown.

```java
return webClient.get()
  .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/nodes/last").queryParams(queryParams).build()) //Problem
  .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token)
  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(String.class)
  .log();
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand '"var"'
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252421700Z  at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$VarArgsTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:370)
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252461800Z  Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252492300Z Error has been observed at the following site(s):
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252521200Z  *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252586100Z  *__checkpoint â‡¢ HTTP GET "/nodeNew/all/last_protected?filter=%5B%7B%22var%22%3A%22report_days%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22%3D%22%2C%22val%22%3A%227%22%7D%5D" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252628200Z Stack trace:
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252666300Z      at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$VarArgsTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:370)
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252699800Z      at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents$QueryUriTemplateVariables.getValue(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:1087)
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252723100Z      at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:263)
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252738600Z      at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.lambda$expandQueryParams$5(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:450)
2021-11-22T11:17:38.252754400Z      at java.base/java.util.Map.forEach(Map.java:713)
```

Maybe is some of configuration to solve it? In queryParams might be another values but not in JSON format, so I would like to avoid do it in that way (that works now, but it have to forward all queryParams not only key "filter"):

```java
return webClient.get()
  .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/nodes/last").queryParam(URLEncoder.encode(queryParams.getFirst("filter"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).build())
```

Comment: your stack trace does not correspond to code you have in the question. "/nodeNew/all/last_protected" is not "/nodes/last". Please provide a reproducable test case with code that shows the behaviour.

Comment: Hi it is correct stackTrace. This is gateway service.
The request is on GET "/nodeNew/all/last_protected", then in RouterFunction I have a handler for that request wihch perfomr GET by WebClient to few microservices and merge the response from them. This webClient perfomr one of the request from the handler

Answer (score 6):

I came across with the same trouble recently and this did the job:

- Create a method that returns a copy of webclient with a custom DefaultUriBuilderFactory

```
public WebClient getWebclientNoEncoded() {
    DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(this.baseUrl); //Here comes your base url
    factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
    return this.webClient.mutate()
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .uriBuilderFactory(factory)
        .build();
}
```

And then in the client method:

```
apiClient.getWebclientNoEncoded()
            .get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .path("/foo")
                .queryParam(UriUtils.encodeQueryParam(myJsonString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()))
                .build())
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, bearerToken)
            .retrieve()
```

*PD. Sorry about my poor english.*

Comment: Thanks; this worked.  For those who may be wondering: the `DefaultUriBuilderFactory` class has a no-args constructor, so it is possible to instantiate one without needing to pass in a `baseUrl`.